# mesh is clumping/deforming while posing

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify, pose-mode

[image]

I've rigged the model using rigify and while posing I came across an issue. The mesh was deforming in a weird way while posing(as you can see near the elbow in the image) I've applied the scale and moved the armature on top of the modifier stack, nothing helped

Comment: you may need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode, in that case find the layer where the deforming bones are

Comment: Weight paint is right I checked

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Got the solution, The problem was the topology thanks for the help

Comment: Here's a good wiki [article](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Limb_Topology) about this topic. Elbows and knees specfically are known for issues with topology and deformation.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution, the problem was the topology.

Comment: Could you please add additional details to your answer? Perhaps you can show what the problem with the topology and how you solved it.